# Google Caja: Sample html4 def file?

Tags: javascript, google-caja

I'm trying to implement this [Introduction Tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer) to sanitize HTML using Caja's JSHtmlSanitizer.

I'm getting a `reference is not defined` error at line 1056 in [html-sanitizer.js](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/html-sanitizer.js) because the variable `html4` is undefined. I believe this is a definition file. Where can I can get a sample of this definition file? I think I found a [very old def file](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/html4-defs.js?spec=svn1950&r=1950) that dates back in 2008 and it's no longer in the latest version of the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML defs file is built from the schema JSON by Caja's build system. The minimum build operation is:

```
$ ant pluginc
```

which will leave the built file at `ant-lib/com/google/caja/plugin/html4-defs.js`.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. I built the entire project on Ubuntu before I read this answer. I couldn't get the project to build on Windows though.